# auto search the keyword in textarea

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This is my coding. This coding allows me to search the keyword in my database and it worked fine. But how can i search the keyword without click the search button? What i want is same as the search function in the google search. It can automatically help you search and review without hit any button.

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1"> 
    <title>Search  Contacts</title> 
  </head> 
  <p><body> 
    <h3>Search  Contacts Details</h3> 
    <p>You  may search either by first or last name</p> 
    <form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="searchform"> 
      <input  type="text" name="question"> 
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
    </form> 

    <?php 
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 
  if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['question'])){ 
  $question=$_POST['question']; 

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"search")or die(mysqli_error($con));;


  $sql="SELECT  id , question FROM question WHERE question LIKE '%" . $question .  "%'"; 
  //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
  $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
          $question  =$row['question'];  
          $id=$row['id']; 

  echo "<ul>\n"; 
  echo "<li>" . " " . $question .  "</li>\n"; 
  echo "</ul>"; 
  } 
  } 
  else{ 
  echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
  } 
  } 
  } 
?> 
  </body> 
</html> 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way Google does it is a bit different. However, what you can do is use JavaScript (jQuery is probably easiest for you here) to send a *XHR*, which would retrieve the results. This would look something like this

```js
$('input[name="question"]').on('keyup', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "search.php?go",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            query: e.target.val()
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        // Output your data however you want
    });
}
```

Of course, you could also use the `GET` HTTP method, that's all your preference.

Now, aside from this, it *looks* like you have a SQL injection vulnerability in your query. Essentially, if I would input `'DROP DATABASE question` as my search query, that would drop your database. What you should be doing is using prepared statements using `Mysql::prepare`, see the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

---

Final note: Google does not do it this way. The best way to achieve blazing fast search results is using WebSockets to maintain a socket connection to your server, and letting the search run through a document database such as Elasticsearch, which is optimised for full-text search.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

give ID to your input field...

```
<div class="content">
<input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" placeholder="Search Here" />
<div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Step 2:

On keyUp search variable is cathed into vaiable and passed via AJAX to "findit.php"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = \'search=\'+ searchid;
if(searchid!=\'\')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "findit.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").on("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find(\'.name\').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $(\'#searchid\').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$(\'#searchid\').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>
```

Step 3:

Now create a php file having name "findit.php" and use the below code

```
include('conn.php'); //this is your DB connection file
if($_POST)
{
    $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['search']);
    $qry = mysqli_query($connection,"select col_name from tbl_name where col_name like '%$q%' order by col_name LIMIT 7");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $col_name   = $row['col_name'];
        $b_res = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
        $final_res = str_ireplace($q, $b_res, $col_name);
        ?>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: may i ask what is the result of this coding? Do i need to do anything or just type the keyword inside the textarea? because it does not haven any respond when i try.

Comment: you have to replace column name , db connection and respective id ..thats all.And it should work after that

Comment: no any error. It just cant show anything. Did you mind to help me check the code?I'm so sorry because i'm just a beginner and not so familiar with the coding.

Comment: it's AJAX my friend...it won't show any error in browser directly..open browser console and see in network->xhr ...
and type any keyword now

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL